# Changing the date format in Access 2010

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

I want to show the `Purchase_Date` in `dd/mm/yy` format . I already set the Format in form properties as `dd/mm/yy`

[image]

When i select a cell in database view it shows the date in `dd/mm/yy` but it still shows the date in `mm/dd/yy` otherwise

[image]

[image]

I need `05/02/14` to show as `02/05/14` at all times

Comment: It's even weirder than that, you're specifying a 2-digit year, but when you have the cell selected (and it's correctly showing mm/dd) you're getting a 4 digit year.

Comment: What I think is that you need to check your settings from the control panel's Region and Language area.

Comment: @AnasTasadduq I need the date to show the same way on any machine

Comment: @user2650277 - Why do you want the date to be in that format on every machine?

Comment: @AnasTasadduq for consistency and i don't want to rely on system language setting

Answer (score 1):

This is by design. When the control gets focus, it will revert to the default format as to the settings in Windows.

A workaround can be to use three concatenated textboxes, but it requires some code to operate nicely.

Answer (score 0):

You have to go to the Region and Language in the Control Panel and choose "English (Autralia)" as the format in the formats tab. Then change the short date format from the option below as you require. The format you want is available there.

Edit:
A better way to do it is to apply your own format. In the Format property of the properties of the Date/Time field, you can type in the format you want using [placeholders and separators](https://support.office.com/en-za/article/Format-the-date-and-time-field-in-Access-47fbbdc1-52fa-416a-b8d5-ba24d881b698#placeholders).

Hope this solves your problem.

Comment: I already typed `dd/mm/yy` in the format property check my first pic